# How can I detect the browser window being closed via Alt+F4 or clicking the window's close button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to close a session in my application when user closes a window by pressing the close button in the title bar or using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> keyboard combo.

I am able to handle X using the code below, but this is not handling <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. I also tried `onbeforeunload` but this is not calling the function at all. I am testing with IE9.

```
<body onunload = "closingWindow()">

<script>
    function closingWindow(){
        if((window.event.clientX<0) || window.event.clientY<0)){
            //Ajax call to close session
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Jaguar: if you're going to go in and format keyboard combinations, please try to fix other typos and grammatical errors at the same time. Oh, and also **make sure what you're formatting is actually a keystroke** - TNina here wasn't talking about the X *key*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `window.onbeforeunload`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/umxfr/1/)**

```
window.onbeforeunload= function(){
    // Ajax call to close session
}
```

Hit `alt+f4` in the demo and you will notice the alert before it closes as well.

Comment: Ya i tried onbeforeunload aswell i am not sure why window is not able to call that event . The function is never called even on click of X if i use onbeforeunload in place of onunload . I am using IE8 . My window opens in a popup from main window . closing the popup should trigger this

Comment: more over this will be called even when a page referesh or navigate from one page to other i just want this to happen when a window is closed

Comment: any ideas on how to detect an Alt F4